# When alert is called JQuery function is returned?

Tags: jquery

onclick event returns Jquery function
I think its object window---

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="update();">update</a>

function update()
{
  var temp = $('#textareaid').html;
  alert(temp);
}

returns---



 function (a){return V(this,function(a){var b=this[0]||{},c=0,d=this.length;if(void 0===a)return 1===b.nodeType?b.innerHTML.replace(fb,""):void 0;if(!("string"!=typeof a||mb.test(a)||!k.htmlSerialize&&gb.test(a)||!k.leadingWhitespace&&hb.test(a)||rb[(jb.exec(a)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase()])){a=a.replace(ib,"<$1></$2>");try{for(;d>c;c++)b=this[c]||{},1===b.nodeType&&(m.cleanData(ub(b,!1)),b.innerHTML=a);b=0}catch(e){}}b&&this.empty().append(a)},null,a,arguments.length)}
```

Answer (score 1):

The get inner html function of jquery is `.html` and if you want to execute the function do `.html()`, so it returns the inner html. In your case, if you want to get the value of your textarea, use the jquery function `.val()` Your modified code:

```
function update()
{
  var temp = $('#textareaid').val();
  alert(temp);
}
```

Here you can find the API of the jQuery .val() : http://api.jquery.com/val/
and the API of the jQuery .html() : http://api.jquery.com/html/

**Short explanation:**
In javascript you define a function like a variable:

```
var a = function(params) {
  //do something
}
```

if you want to alert the value of this variable call `alert(a);` and alert tries to display the value (you get the function-definition). To execute your function you have to call `alert(a(params));` and here you can pass some parameter.

Comment: ...maybe your element `#textareaid` isn't found?

Comment: other part is design, main part is anchor tag and then function is defined in script tag

Comment: console.log(this)
returns window object

Comment: You want to alert the html from the tag with the id "#textareaid" is that right?

Comment: Yeah, but when tried to log then window object is displayed

Comment: i've updated my post, if you want the value of an textarea element use `.val()`

Comment: undefined is displayed

Comment: Is your script and jquery at the bottom of your html page? Or do you use `$(document).ready(function(){...});`?

Comment: Do you really have an element above your script tag looking like that? `<textarea id="textareaid"></textarea>`

Comment: I tried it with that code and it works fine: `<html>
<head>
</head>
<body> 
 <textarea id="textareaid"></textarea>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="update();">update</a>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
<script>
function update()
{
  var temp = $('#textareaid').val();
  alert(temp);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>`